# Github Forked repository messed up

Tags: git, github

I have forked a github repository and I dont have a clone of it locally.
Now many changes and commits are made and many fetches from upstream are made.

Now I want my forked repo fresh as the current upstream repo.(In other words, I want my forked repo cloned as current upstream repo).

How can I do that?

Comment: Clone the upstream repo again and discard your fork?

Comment: In GitHub there's a button to update a fork from its upstream. Is that what you are looking for?